# Why does this thread cause my application to hang up after multiple executions?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I created this test program to try to understand threading a little better:

```
namespace ThreadTest
{
    public class Class1
    {
        static Number number = new Number();

        static public void Go()
        {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(IncrementNumber));
            t1.Start();
            IncrementNumber();
        }

        public static void IncrementNumber()
        {
            number.Inc();
        }
    }

    public class Number
    {
        int x = 0;

        public void Inc()
        {

                x++;
                Debug.Write(x);
                Debug.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return x.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I am just executing it from the Immediate Window by calling ThreadTest.Class1.Go(). I noticed that from one execution to the next, as long as it doesn't have to recompile, the static members remain in memory and it continues to reuse them.

Here's what the immediate window looks like after four successive executions:

```
ThreadTest.Class1.Go()
2
1
Expression has been evaluated and has no value
ThreadTest.Class1.Go()
3
4Expression has been evaluated and has no value
ThreadTest.Class1.Go()
ThreadTest.Class1.Go()
An expression evaluation is already in progress.
```

The first execution looks as I would expect.

The second execution didn't manage to write the final Environment.NewLine. Is this possibly because execution from the main thread finished before execution on the t1 so that t1 had time to write the number, but not the new line? That seems unlikely but it's the only explanation I can come up with right now.

The third execution just hangs, which is evidenced by the output of the fourth attempt to execute it. Why would it hang?

Comment: Actually your "application" has a little bit _random_ behavior. You create a thread that executes just once (what's the point of a thread then?) but you don't dispose it. You store values in static variables (without any synchronization between them and x isn't even volatile) and you execute it inside immediate window...with all these stuff...does it really matter why it hangs?

Comment: @Adriano All good points. I understand I could go get a text book example of a proper way to do something like this, but I'm trying to understand what's really going on. I have no clue how it could possibly hang as there is absolutely nothing in this program that should ever be waiting for anything or blocking anything. I can foresee a future problem where something like this might happen on a large program that calls a particular routine multiple times. I'd rather figure this out on a small example so that I understand what's happening in case I run into it on something more signifanct.

Comment: I agree but you should try with a simple console application. There you add more unknown variables (what's going on inside immediate window?).

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, execution of the main thread could have halted at that point.

A good indication that this is happening is if you get different output on different runs.

You will need to describe "hangs" a bit better to fully answer that aspect.  If there was simply no output, that would indicate the main thread finished before any output from `t1`.  If there is just no output but the program does not end, try breaking execution and looking at which line each thread is on for clues.

Try to Join `t1` in your main thread to prevent the program from exiting before you are ready for it to.

Comment: Joining t1 fixes it as I suspected it would, but that still left me wondering why it hangs without that line (and there are situations where you wouldn't want to join so I still wanted to figure it out). The only variance in output (with the original code) from one trial to the next is that sometimes the 4 doesn't get printed either. I think this supports the notion that the main thread is ending before t1. And I believe the reason it hangs on the next execution has something to do with the fact that t1 didn't get to finish on the previous run.

Comment: I would think it should be instantiating a new thread each time and discarding the old one (even if it still continues to exist) though so I don't totally understand why that would make it hang.

Comment: Once the main thread ends, the process exits.  All traces of `t1` should be eliminated at that point.

Comment: Well... it seems that it only hangs after the main thread exits before t1 finishes. I think Adriano had a good point about running it as a console app instead of using the immediate window... I tried that and it never hung anymore. (To be clear, I turned it into a console app and in the Main method I called Go() like 25 times in a row to simulate what I was doing by calling it from the immediate window).